# Bluetooth pop-up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I am trying to test out bluetooth connectivity with some code. Whenever I try to scan for bluetooth devices I do not get a pop-up to allow for it so it keeps waiting for it. I know the code works because we are working in group and it works on the MacOS computer my partner has but it is not working on my windows. I mainly want it to scan for an ESP with BLE. I already enabled the 'Experimental Web Platform features' and the 'Use the new permissions backend for Web Bluetooth' flags and made sure my Chrome is updated and made sure the permissions for bluetooth scanning and devices are enabled.

```
console.log("Init");

document.getElementById("scan").onclick = scan;
navigator.bluetooth.addEventListener("advertisementreceived", (event) => {
  console.log("Advertisement", event);
});

async function scanDevices() {
  const devices = await navigator.bluetooth.getDevices();
  console.log(devices);
}

async function scan() {
  console.log("Scanning...");
  let options = {
    acceptAllAdvertisements: true,
  };

  try {
    log("Requesting Bluetooth Scan with options: " + JSON.stringify(options));
    const scan = await navigator.bluetooth.requestLEScan(options);

    log("Scan started with:");
    log(" acceptAllAdvertisements: " + scan.acceptAllAdvertisements);
    log(" active: " + scan.active);
    log(" keepRepeatedDevices: " + scan.keepRepeatedDevices);
    log(" filters: " + JSON.stringify(scan.filters));

    navigator.bluetooth.addEventListener("advertisementreceived", (event) => {
      log("Advertisement received.");
      log("  Device Name: " + event.device.name);
      log("  Device ID: " + event.device.id);
      log("  RSSI: " + event.rssi);
      log("  TX Power: " + event.txPower);
      log("  UUIDs: " + event.uuids);
      event.manufacturerData.forEach((valueDataView, key) => {
        logDataView("Manufacturer", key, valueDataView);
      });
      event.serviceData.forEach((valueDataView, key) => {
        logDataView("Service", key, valueDataView);
      });
    });

    setTimeout(stopScan, 10000);

    function stopScan() {
      console.log("Scan result", scan);
      log("Stopping scan...");
      scan.stop();
      log("Stopped.  scan.active = " + scan.active);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    log("Argh! " + error);
  }
}

function log(c) {
  console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [requestDevice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/requestDevice) to pop up chooser UI.

```
const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options)
```

Comment: Where should I add this line, because i have tried and either it does nothing or give me an error

Comment: See working demo: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html?allDevices=true.

Comment: Problem with this is that it is for pairing i just want it to scan.

Comment: One cannot scan in the browser without user interaction.